# Using the Arduino serial monitor and nested loops to talk to different peripherals

Tags: loops, while-loop, serial-port, arduino

I'm making an arduino project that reads in some values from some [Atlas Scientific](http://atlas-scientific.com/product_pages/kits/ec-kit.html) probes. There is example code for how to communicate with only one device using the serial monitor, and I'm trying to port that to 'select' which probe I want to talk to using the serial monitor. The problem is that the example code just waits for serial input in the loop(). It looks like this:

```
void loop(){                                                                   //here we go....

  if (input_stringcomplete){                                                   //if a string from the PC has been recived in its entierty 
      Serial2.print(inputstring);                                              //send that string to the Atlas Scientific product
      inputstring = "";                                                        //clear the string:
      input_stringcomplete = false;                                            //reset the flage used to tell if we have recived a completed string from the PC
      }

 if (sensor_stringcomplete){                                                   //if a string from the Atlas Scientific product has been recived in its entierty 
      Serial.println(sensorstring);                                            //send that string to to the PC's serial monitor
      sensorstring = "";                                                       //clear the string:
      sensor_stringcomplete = false;                                           //reset the flage used to tell if we have recived a completed string from the Atlas Scientific product
      }
 }
```

So basically, you type in a command and hit enter, it sends the command to the probe. The probe does its magic, and reports a  value back to you. Pretty straightforward.
I'm trying to use case statements to select which probe I want to talk to (there's also a  temperature sensor that doesn't use this protocol). I'm trying to use a while loop inside the case statements to talk to my peripherals.

```
void loop(){                                                                  
// read the selection
 if (Serial.available()>0) {
   int inByte = Serial.read();
     switch(inByte) {
       case '1':
      //read pH
  Serial.print("pH");
  while (inputstring != "break"){
  if (input_stringcomplete){                                               //if a string from the PC has been recived in its entierty 
  Serial3.print(inputstring);                                              //send that string to the Atlas Scientific product
  Serial.print(inputstring);
  inputstring = "";                                                        //clear the string:
  input_stringcomplete = false;                                            //reset the flage used to tell if we have recived a completed string from the PC
  }

 if (sensor_stringcomplete){                                                   //if a string from the Atlas Scientific product has been recived in its entierty 
      Serial.println(sensorstring);                                            //send that string to to the PC's serial monitor
      sensorstring = "";                                                       //clear the string:
      sensor_stringcomplete = false;                                           //reset the flage used to tell if we have recived a completed string from the Atlas Scientific product
      }
      }

      case '2':
      //read EC
Serial.print("EC");      
while (inputstring != "break"){
          if (input_stringcomplete){                                               //if a string from the PC has been recived in its entierty 
          Serial2.print(inputstring);                                              //send that string to the Atlas Scientific product
          Serial.print(inputstring);                                               //debug
          inputstring = "";                                                        //clear the string:
          input_stringcomplete = false;                                            //reset the flage used to tell if we have recived a completed string from the PC
          }

     if (sensor_stringcomplete){                                                   //if a string from the Atlas Scientific product has been recived in its entierty 
          Serial.println(sensorstring);                                            //send that string to to the PC's serial monitor
          sensorstring = "";                                                       //clear the string:
          sensor_stringcomplete = false;                                           //reset the flage used to tell if we have recived a completed string from the Atlas Scientific product
          }
          }
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

Like I said, I'm trying to use the while loops to run the individual terminal serial communication with the individual sensors, and be able to type "break" into the terminal to go back to my case statements and select another sensor. The while loop idea isn't working at all. I added debug lines to echo my commands, and it's not even doing that. Is there a better way to do these nested loops?

Here's the full program for reference.

```
/*
This software was made to demonstrate how to quickly get your Atlas Scientific product running on the Arduino platform.
An Arduino MEGA 2560 board was used to test this code.
This code was written in the Arudino 1.0 IDE
Modify the code to fit your system.
**Type in a command in the serial monitor and the Atlas Scientific product will respond.**
**The data from the Atlas Scientific product will come out on the serial monitor.**
Code efficacy was NOT considered, this is a demo only.
The TX3 line goes to the RX pin of your product.
The RX3 line goes to the TX pin of your product.
Make sure you also connect to power and GND pins to power and a common ground.
Open TOOLS > serial monitor, set the serial monitor to the correct serial port and set the baud rate to 38400.
Remember, select carriage return from the drop down menu next to the baud rate selection; not "both NL & CR".
*/
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

// Data wire is plugged into pin 30 on the Arduino
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 32
#define TEMPERATURE_PRECISION 9
// Setup a oneWire instance to communicate with any OneWire devices (not just Maxim/Dallas temperature ICs)
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
// Pass our oneWire reference to Dallas Temperature. 
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
// arrays to hold device address
DeviceAddress insideThermometer;

String inputstring = "";                                                       //a string to hold incoming data from the PC
String sensorstring = "";                                                      //a string to hold the data from the Atlas Scientific product
boolean input_stringcomplete = false;                                          //have we received all the data from the PC
boolean sensor_stringcomplete = false;                                         //have we received all the data from the Atlas Scientific product

String inputString = "";         // a string to hold incoming data
boolean stringComplete = false;  // whether the string is complete

int numberOfDevices; // Number of temperature devices found
DeviceAddress tempDeviceAddress;

void setup(void){                                                                //set up the hardware
    Serial.begin(9600);                                                       //set baud rate for the hardware serial port_0 to 38400
    Serial3.begin(38400);                                                     //set baud rate for software serial port_3 to 38400
    Serial2.begin(38400);                                                     //set baud rate for software serial port_3 to 38400
    inputstring.reserve(5);                                                   //set aside some bytes for receiving data from the PC
    sensorstring.reserve(30);                                                 //set aside some bytes for receiving data from Atlas Scientific produc
    // locate devices on the bus
    Serial.print("Locating temperature devices...");
    sensors.begin();
    // Grab a count of devices on the wire
    numberOfDevices = sensors.getDeviceCount();
    Serial.print("Found ");
    Serial.print(sensors.getDeviceCount(), DEC);
    Serial.println(" devices.");
     for(int i=0;i<numberOfDevices; i++)
  {
    if(sensors.getAddress(tempDeviceAddress, i))
    {
        sensors.setResolution(tempDeviceAddress, TEMPERATURE_PRECISION);
        }
  }   
    Serial.println("Type 1 to read pH, 2 to read EC, or 3 to read temperature.");
  }
//for reading pH/EC
void serialEvent() {                                                         //if the hardware serial port_0 receives a char              
               char inchar = (char)Serial.read();                               //get the char we just received
               inputstring += inchar;                                           //add it to the inputString
               if(inchar == '\r') {input_stringcomplete = true;}                //if the incoming character is a <CR>, set the flag
               input_stringcomplete = true;
              }  
void serialEvent3(){                                                         //if the hardware serial port_3 receives a char 
              char inchar = (char)Serial3.read();                              //get the char we just received
              sensorstring += inchar;                                          //add it to the inputString
              if(inchar == '\r') {sensor_stringcomplete = true;}               //if the incoming character is a <CR>, set the flag 
             }
void serialEvent2(){                                                         //if the hardware serial port_3 receives a char 
              char inchar = (char)Serial2.read();                              //get the char we just received
              sensorstring += inchar;                                          //add it to the inputString
              if(inchar == '\r') {sensor_stringcomplete = true;}               //if the incoming character is a <CR>, set the flag 
             }

//for reading temp
void printTemperature(DeviceAddress deviceAddress)
{
  // method 2 - faster
  float tempC = sensors.getTempC(deviceAddress);
  Serial.print("Temp C: ");
  Serial.print(tempC);
  Serial.print(" Temp F: ");
  Serial.println(DallasTemperature::toFahrenheit(tempC)); // Converts tempC to Fahrenheit
}
void printAddress(DeviceAddress deviceAddress)
{
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    if (deviceAddress[i] < 16) Serial.print("0");
    Serial.print(deviceAddress[i], HEX);
  }
}



void loop(){                                                                   //here we go....
// read the selection
 int r = 0; 
 if (Serial.available()>0) {
   int inByte = Serial.read();
     switch(inByte) {
       case '1':
      //read pH
      Serial.print("pH");
      while (inputstring != "break"){
      if (input_stringcomplete){                                               //if a string from the PC has been recived in its entierty 
      Serial3.print(inputstring);                                              //send that string to the Atlas Scientific product
      Serial.print(inputstring);                                               //debug
      inputstring = "";                                                        //clear the string:
      input_stringcomplete = false;                                            //reset the flage used to tell if we have recived a completed string from the PC
      }

 if (sensor_stringcomplete){                                                   //if a string from the Atlas Scientific product has been recived in its entierty 
      Serial.println(sensorstring);                                            //send that string to to the PC's serial monitor
      sensorstring = "";                                                       //clear the string:
      sensor_stringcomplete = false;                                           //reset the flage used to tell if we have recived a completed string from the Atlas Scientific product
      }
      }

      case '2':
      //read EC
      Serial.print("EC");
      while (inputstring != "break"){
      if (input_stringcomplete){                                               //if a string from the PC has been recived in its entierty 
      Serial2.print(inputstring);                                              //send that string to the Atlas Scientific product
      Serial.print(inputstring);                                               //debug
      inputstring = "";                                                        //clear the string:
      input_stringcomplete = false;                                            //reset the flage used to tell if we have recived a completed string from the PC
      }

 if (sensor_stringcomplete){                                                   //if a string from the Atlas Scientific product has been recived in its entierty 
      Serial.println(sensorstring);                                            //send that string to to the PC's serial monitor
      sensorstring = "";                                                       //clear the string:
      sensor_stringcomplete = false;                                           //reset the flage used to tell if we have recived a completed string from the Atlas Scientific product
      }
      }

      case '3':
      // call sensors.requestTemperatures() to issue a global temperature 
      // request to all devices on the bus
      Serial.print("Requesting temperatures...");
      sensors.requestTemperatures(); // Send the command to get temperatures
      Serial.println("DONE");
      // Loop through each device, print out temperature data
      for(int i=0;i<numberOfDevices; i++)
      {
        // Search the wire for address
        if(sensors.getAddress(tempDeviceAddress, i))
        {
        // Output the device ID
        Serial.print("Temperature for device: ");
        Serial.println(i,DEC);

        // It responds almost immediately. Let's print out the data
        printTemperature(tempDeviceAddress); // Use a simple function to print out the data
        } 
    //else ghost device! Check your power requirements and cabling

        }
      break;
    }
   }
}
```

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the language used by Arduino, but it looks like you only have a break statement for case 3 of your switch.  This will cause cases 1 and 2 to flow into 3 if there is indeed a break required.  Sometimes this is useful behavior but I am guessing that it isn't in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I know a good library for the arduino being the middle ware between sensors and pc

have a look here
https://code.google.com/p/arduino-serial-packet/

and here
https://code.google.com/p/arduino-serial-configuration-menu/

Answer (score 0):

This example demonstrates how control “drops through” unless a break statement is used:

```
BOOL fClosing = FALSE;

...

switch( wParam )
{
  case IDM_F_CLOSE:       // File close command.
    fClosing = TRUE;
    // fall through

  case IDM_F_SAVE:        // File save command.
    if( document->IsDirty() )
      if( document->Name() == "UNTITLED" )
        FileSaveAs( document );
      else
        FileSave( document );

    if( fClosing )
      document->Close();

    break;
}
```

The preceding code shows how to take advantage of the fact that case labels do not impede the flow of control. If the switch statement transfers control to `IDM_F_SAVE`, `fClosing` is `FALSE`. Therefore, after the file is saved, the document is not closed. However, if the switch statement transfers control to `IDM_F_CLOSE`, `fClosing` is set to `TRUE`, and the code to save a file is executed.